# Use arrow keys (Up/Down) to move through Combobox Dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I created a combobox for the user to type the right name of an item that he's looking for.

The combobox will suggest the possible values that the user can select.

I did this combobox by using [this guide](https://trumpexcel.com/excel-drop-down-list-with-search-suggestions/).

I found is the only way to select the value is by typing every letter or to click using the mouse in the dropdown list, but I want to allow the user to use the arrows keys to move through the list.

When using that combobox if the user uses the arrow key it selects the first value in the dropdown list therefore removing all other matches.

[image: Example of the problem]

I want when using the arrow keys it won't select the value but scroll through the list until he finds what he needs.

I found some people had the same issue but none of them could help me.

Comment: Have you tried this yet: https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/828998-using-arrow-keys-combo-box ?

Comment: I didnt tried that link but still didnt work. When pressing the arrow the option is not selected but i cant move more than one cell

Answer (score 0):

This function works in ms access vba. not sure about necessary changes for excel vba. I hope it can help.

n.b. the byte link code is faulty (at least for ms access vba) I posted same code as correction there.

```
Public Sub ArrowKeys(ByRef KeyCode As Integer, combo As ComboBox, ByRef Flag As Boolean)
' flag is used to be able to toggle normal action in combo_change()
Select Case KeyCode
    Case vbKeyDown
        KeyCode = 0 ' make sure the action wont be duplicated
        If combo.ListIndex <> combo.ListCount - 1 Then
          combo.Value = combo.ItemData(combo.ListIndex + 1)
          Flag = True
          combo.Dropdown
        Else
          combo.Value = combo.ItemData(0)
          Flag = True
          combo.Dropdown
        End If
   
   Case vbKeyUp
        KeyCode = 0 ' make sure the action wont be duplicated
        If combo.ListIndex = -1 Then ' In case nothingg is selected yet (-1 index)
          combo.Value = combo.ItemData(combo.ListCount - 1)
          combo.Dropdown
        ElseIf combo.ListIndex <> 0 Then
          combo.Value = combo.ItemData(combo.ListIndex - 1)
          Flag = True
          combo.Dropdown
        Else
          combo.Value = combo.ItemData(combo.ListCount - 1)
          Flag = True
          combo.Dropdown
        End If
End Select
End Sub
```